# Repairing poorly formatted tsv

Tags: python, regex

I have a tsv file that has additional tabs that shouldn’t be there.

For example :

```
Col1\tCol2\tCol3
A\t\t1\t1
B\t\t
```

I have tried python's `re` to replace all `\t\t` with a pipe but this causes problems in the second row where there are null values.

Would you have a suggestion on how I can fix row one?

Comment: Try replacing `\t\t` with `\t`.

Comment: start by counting the number of \t in the line, maybe

Comment: In the second row - I won’t have enough columns then. It should Read B ‘’ ‘’ as in there are two null values

Comment: There are an infinite number of wrong ways for the additional tabs to be there. If you can reduce that to a manageable number, the it should be possible to correct those cases. However there is not enough information in your question at this time to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to keep the same number of columns as in the header, in that case, I will do something like this:

```
outputlines = []

# Replace the undesired characters in each line
with open("yourFileNameHere","r") as reader:
    lines = reader.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        # Get the length of each line in order to determine which logic to apply
        if len(line.split("\t")) > 3:
            outputlines.append(line.strip().replace("\t\t","|").replace("\t","|"))
        else:
            outputlines.append(line.strip().replace("\t","|"))

# Write back the file with the new format
with open("myOutputFileName","w") as writer:
    rows = len(outputlines)
    for i in range(rows):
        if i != rows - 1:
            writer.write(f'{outputlines[i]}\n')
        else:
            writer.write(f'{outputlines[i]}')
```

Please lee me know if this helps :D!

Comment: Hi I like the idea. However, my columns could be up to 180 in length. I was hoping that there was some sort of quoted strings embedded in the text file but I couldn’t see any. It’s so frustrated that someone output it will additional tabs !

Comment: I was also thinking of some regex thing but I can’t think of a rule that would preserve column B.